# Google spreadsheets script - grant access to only one sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, permissions, google-sheets

How is access granted to only a specific sheet for the current spreadsheet user?  My idea was to have sheets named with the users email, and only grant access to a sheet which is the same name as user email.

```
function protectSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var num_sheets = ss.getNumSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < num_sheets; i++){
    //setting permission to each sheet
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[i]);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var permissions = sheet.getSheetProtection();
    permissions.setProtected(true);
    sheet.setSheetProtection(permissions);

    // hiding all sheets wich not allowed
    if (ss.getSheets()[i] != email) {
     sheet.hideSheet();
    }
  };
}
```

But the problem is that the email is in an array.  How can an array be used to match against the current user? Is there are another way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
if (ss.getSheets()[i] != email) {
```

Is retrieving an array that contains all of the sheets. (And it retrieves that data every time that line of code is run.  Might be better to read that data just once somewhere else in the code).  You also use the index of `[i]`, which  is getting just one of the sheets out of the array.  But that is an object.  It doesn't return the name.  You want the name.  You need to use the `getSheetName()` method.

```
if (ss.getSheets()[i].getSheetName() != email) {
```

I rewrote your code to get the array of sheets higher up in the code, outside of the `FOR` loop.

```
function protectSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var num_sheets = ss.getNumSheets();

  var arryAllSheetNames = ss.getSheets();
  var thisSheetName = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < num_sheets; i++){
    //set permissions to each sheet
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[i]);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var permissions = sheet.getSheetProtection();
    permissions.setProtected(true);
    sheet.setSheetProtection(permissions);

    thisSheetName = arryAllSheetNames[i].getSheetName();

    // hide all sheets which are not allowed
    if (thisSheetName != email) {
      sheet.hideSheet();
    }
  };
}
```